# Weak convergence does not imply joint weak convergence?

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems, pointwise-convergence

Suppose that $X_n\Rightarrow X$ and $Y_n\Rightarrow Y$ as $n\to\infty$ where "$\Rightarrow$" means convergence in distribution. We know that it does NOT imply that $(X_n,Y_n)\Rightarrow (X,Y)$ as $n\to\infty$.

In the following proof, which step is incorrect?

Proof. Let $g_n(c_n)=E[f(X_n,Y_n)|Y_n=c_n]$ and $g(c)=E[f(X,Y)|Y=c]$, where $f$ is any given bounded and continuous function and $c_n\to c$ as $n\to\infty$. Because $(X_n,c_n)\Rightarrow (X,c)$ as $n\to\infty$, we have
$$
g_n(c_n)\to g(c) \quad \mbox{as $n\to\infty$}. 
$$
Then, by continuous-mapping theorem, we have $g_n(Y_n)\to g(Y)$ as $n\to\infty$, i.e.,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} E[f(X_n,Y_n)|Y_n]=E[f(X,c)|c=Y]. 
$$
By dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}E[f(X_n,Y_n)]=\lim_{n\to\infty}E[E[f(X_n,Y_n)|Y_n]]=E\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}E[f(X_n,Y_n)|Y_n]\right]=E[E[f(X,c)|c=Y]]=E[f(X,Y)],
$$
which shows that $(X_n,Y_n)\Rightarrow (X,Y)$ as $n\to\infty$.$~~~~~~~~~~$ QED.

Note: I use the "extended" continuous-mapping theorem in the proof where there are a sequence of functions $g_n$ instead of a function $g$, see [http://www.bios.unc.edu/~kosorok/lecture09.pdf](http://www.bios.unc.edu/%7Ekosorok/lecture09.pdf) (Page 23)

This proof leads us to an incorrect conclusion. So, I am wondering which step in the proof is incorrect?

Thank you!

Comment: First, I would say I'm not convinced by the argument that $g_n(c_n) \rightarrow g(c)$.  It's also not obvious to me that $g_n(c_n)$ is even uniquely defined, let alone continuous.  Beyond that, the continuous mapping theorem doesn't apply because we have a sequence of functions instead of just a single function.

Comment: @user6247850 Could you explain why $g_n(c_n)$ may not uniquely defined? I have cited a reference for the "extended" continuous-mapping theorem with a sequence of functions.

Comment: $g_n(c_n)$ may not be uniquely defined if $\mathbb{P}(Y_n = c_n) = 0$, i.e. you are conditioning on a null event.  The extended theorem you cited would apply, but there is still a gap in showing $g_n(c_n) \rightarrow g(c)$.

Comment: @user6247850 Sorry, I don't get your point. Let's consider the case where the supports of $Y_n$ and $Y$ are $\mathbb{R}$. In this case, the $g_n$ and $g$ are well-defined (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) although their conditions are null events.

Comment: There are some cases where $g_n$ and $g$ are well-defined even though their conditions are null events, but "the supports of $Y_n$ and $Y$ are $\mathbb{R}$" is an additional assumption you have placed on the random variables.  If that is not the case, I don't see how you could get uniqueness of $g_n$ or $g$.  But you still haven't addressed the biggest gap in showing $g_n(c_n) \rightarrow g(c)$.

Comment: @user6247850 I don't think the supports being $\mathbb{R}$ is a necessary condition, but we could just discuss this example with the supports are $\mathbb{R}$. In this case, we have $(X_n,c_n)\Rightarrow(X,c)$. Then, by the portmanteau thm, we have $E[f(X_n,Y_n)|Y_n=c_n]=E[f(X_n,c_n)]\to E[f(X,c)]=E[f(X,Y)|Y=c]$, i.e., $g_n(c_n)\to g(c)$. Is it correct? thanks.

Comment: $E[f(X_n,Y_n)|Y_n=c_n] \ne E[f(X_n,c_n)]$ when $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are not independent.  If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ *are* independent, then we do indeed have joint convergence in distribution of $(X_n,Y_n)$.

Comment: @user6247850 thank you!